# MySQL optimization can be solved?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, optimization

I Have a table that holds data about 'deals'. Deals are either closed or opened, and are marks so in an 'is_closed' column. (which is, or course, indexed).

there are about 10,000 'open' rows, and 10,000,000 'closed' rows. Each 'open' row is updated about once per second. (Only not indexed fields are updated here). Once a row is 'closed', it will never again be updated. (only read).

I never need to run a select that handles both open and closed rows, so the question is;
Should I divide the table to two tables, (open and closed), with the same structure?

The cons of a single table is that every second I run an update on a 10,000,000 rows table.
The cons of two tables, is that there is a kind of code duplication, and that when closing 'deals' I need to remove them from one table, and add to the other.

Comment: If I understood it correctly, you have a query like:

    UPDATE t1 SET c1 = 'ham', c2 = 'spam' WHERE is_closed = 0;

That would probably use the index, so I don't see why this would be a problem. Table seems relatively small. Any numbers that show how 'slow' it is? Or EXPLAIN output?

Comment: How often are rows set to is_closed? Is updating the index a bottleneck? MyISAM? InnoDB?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can [partition](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html) your table by state column, so you will logically have 1 table. [List partition](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-list.html) seems to be appropriate in your case. Then you can go further and sub-partition 'closed' partition if needed...

Answer (score 1):

If Ratio of Close vs Open is >= 1000 (as you mentioned) then it would be better to make two different tables.

You can avoid code duplication by using polymorphism. You can make one Abstract base class of deal by name **AbstractDeal** and then extend two concrete classes **OpenDeal** and **CloseDeal**. You can map these two concrete classes with your tables respectively.

I Hope this would be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Boolean (true and false, or 1 and 0) columns like yours are fine in some situations, but if you ever find yourself indexing such a column, you've probably crossed the line.

If the values were distributed evenly (50% true and 50% false), MySQL wouldn't even use the index anyway, unless it were a covering index. The cost of seeking each row via the secondary index where a large percentage of the dataset will be returned is expensive, so MySQL will do a simple table scan instead.

In your case, since you're querying against the smaller distribution (1% false), MySQL may actually utilize the index.

However, then you have to wonder why you have to store so many true values in the index that aren't even being used, yet, they slow down index updates, and just plain waste space.

**...REVISED...**

Instead, consider storing the index outside in the form of another table. Consider adding a table named open_deals with the following structure, where deal_id is the primary key for both deals and open_deals:

```
deal_id
----------
100
121
135
```

To get your open deals, simply do this:

```
SELECT deals.*
FROM open_deals
STRAIGHT_JOIN deals
  ON deals.deal_id = open_deals.deal_id
```

We use a straight join since we always know we'll be joining from left to right, and we're saving MySQL from having to think about it.

Since open_deals only consists of a single indexed column, the index will act as a covering index. On a properly configured, beefy server, the index will be stored in memory, so the table will be very fast.

The join, internally, will be similar to using your original secondary index, but without the overhead of all of those unused values.

For the best performance, ensure that new values are appended to the end of the open_deals table, or in other words, all new values should be greater than the last, but you're doing that anyway.

To set a deal to open, append it to the open_deals table, and to mark it as closed, delete the id from the open_deals table.

The advantage here is that you're not having to move records between tables, having to update the other indexes (even worse with InnoDB's clustered index). The only index that gets updated here is the rather small index on the open_deals table.

Comment: *"Indexes don't store NULL values"* Can you add a link to documentation on this matter?

Comment: @ypercube, bah, you know I can't because it's not true. :) I really thought this was true because COUNT() doesn't count them, but now that I think about it, MySQL still needs to store them for ORDER BY clauses and such. I'll delete my answer for now, and maybe change it to my other idea.

Comment: @ypercube, what do you think of this one?

Answer (score 1):

Divide them in two tables. I see no cons:

- *The cons of two tables, is that there is a kind of code duplication*

So what? You aim for performance, not less lines of code.

- *and that when closing 'deals' I need to remove them from one table, and add to the other.*

A few more lines of code. Some UPDATE procedures will be converted to INSERT/DELETE ones.

---

The pros are that :

- You have one index less, in both tables.
- Any compound index (that included the `open/closed` flag) will be a bit narrower.
- And more important, all your indices in the table with the high traffic will be much smaller.

Answer (score 0):

As long as both tables are in the same tablespace, you will get next to nothing from splitting or partittioning the table - the benefits of code simplicity strongly favour keeping it in one.

InnoDB will do row-level locking, so you will not end up with your closed deals blocking open ones.